# Microsoft office word web addin issue

Tags: c#, jquery, vsto, word-web-addins

I am new to Word web addin and created a sidepane addin for Word using VS2017 c#.

The addin webproject has a `default.aspx` page with a checkbox and office.js cdn link inside page head section. On checkbox onchecked event I am getting content from a word document file using jQuery Ajax call and inserting result in active word document. My code is working fine on local pc but after deploying to test server and adding catlog able to see sidepane with `default.aspx` and on checkbox checked event retrieve result is not getting inserted into the active word document.

CND link: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js

Things I have tried.

1. Checked IIS logs (No issue found)
2. Checked browser network tab by running web project as startup but found no issues.
3. Checked Manifest.xml default links all are point to the hosted server. Please help getting out of this below is my code

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var docContent = '';
        function onchkChange(content) {
            var param;
            var id = content;
            var ischecked = $('#' + content).prop('checked');

            if (id == 'chk_Q1OP1') {
                param = { "startPoint": "ConfidentialInformation", "endPoint": "EndofClauseCI", "isChecked": ischecked }
            }
           
            if (docContent == '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://localhost:2345/Default.aspx/chk_Q1",
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {                        
                        if (data.d != '' && data.d != undefined) {
                            docContent = data.d;
                            if (param.isChecked) {
                                inserToWord(extractString(docContent, param.startPoint, param.endPoint));
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data, success, error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            } else {
              
                if (param.isChecked) {
                    inserToWord(extractString(docContent, param.startPoint, param.endPoint));
                }
            }
        }
        function inserToWord(text) {             
            Word.run(function (context) {
                let cursorLocation = context.document.getSelection();
                context.load(cursorLocation);
                cursorLocation.insertText('--@@@--\n'+text+'\n--@@@--', Word.InsertLocation.end);
                return context.sync();
            });
        }

        function extractString(text, startPoint, endPoint) {       
            var startIndex = text.indexOf(startPoint);
            var endIndex = text.indexOf(endPoint);
            var result = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            return result
        }
</script>
```